# Minesweeper - Online Judge "Wrong answer" although it works on Netbeans

Tags: java

I was trying to submit Minesweeper problem on UVa (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1130)

Sample input:

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
```

Sample output:

```
*100
2210
1*10
1110
```

I have developed the code on NetBeans. I have tested it and it was working fine, but when I try to submit it on UVa it result a Wrong Answer for the submition.

I have two questions:
1)What is the problem in my code?
2)What should I use and what shouldn`t I use while coding for UVa?

-If there is a different standard I should follow, please advice

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String REGEX_WHITESPACE = "\\s+";
        String cleanLine = line.trim().replaceAll(REGEX_WHITESPACE, " ");
        String[] numChar = cleanLine.split(REGEX_WHITESPACE);
        int n = new Integer(numChar[0]).intValue();
        int m = new Integer(numChar[1]).intValue();
        char[][] mine = new char[n][m];
        char[] curLine;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                line=reader.readLine();
                cleanLine = line.trim().replaceAll(REGEX_WHITESPACE, " ");
                curLine = cleanLine.toCharArray();
                if(curLine.length==m){
                    mine[i]=curLine;
                }
        }
        int starsCount=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                if(mine[i][j]=='*'){
                    System.out.print('*');
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        if (mine[i][j - 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i][j + 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i-1][j] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i+1][j] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i-1][j - 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i-1][j + 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i+1][j - 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        if (mine[i+1][j + 1] == '*') {
                            starsCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if(j==m-1){
                        System.out.println(starsCount);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print(starsCount);
                    }
                    starsCount=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know much about the online judge.  Is it expecting output in stdout, or is it expecting function calls?

Comment: @Makoto It is required to submit a class Main and it main() contain the code to be run. No more. I have submitted a problem before in this standard

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but your code for checking neighbours is really, really ugly. I suggest instead making an enumeration of all possible directions, each direction having an `xdelta` and a `ydelta`, making a function that checks a neighbour in one supplied direction, and enumerate over all possible directions calling the method.

Comment: @Patashuv yes, you are right. I have to check in better way. But I was trying to avoid the exception if the required position is not exist. I think this is not the problem.

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy Indeed it isn't the problem. But seeing code that does directional things 8 times over really bugs me, and I want you to know the right way to do it - something like http://pastebin.com/06yNW2TD is how I would implement it. Note the use of the Direction enumeration, iterating over all Directions and bounds checking inside the method (= no need to throw and catch costly exceptions). I haven't tried to compile/test this, it's just an example.

Comment: Reading the site, it seems like there could be multiple fields, and your code only seems to handle one. Also the site says to output "Field #num:" before each field (which I also don't see in your code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one thing you can look at.

When you know your program has to give output that looks exactly like a sample, e.g. in your case

```
*100
2210
1*10
1110
```

You should check for hidden whitespace - such as spaces, tabs, new lines (which can be `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` format). In particular, common gotchas are:

-Is there a line break after the last line, or not?

-Does it matter if your line breaks are `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`?

-If you have extra spaces anywhere, or a line break before you begin the output, does it consider the sample to not match it?

-If there are tabs or lots of spaces, does using tabs instead of spaces or vice versa make the sample not considered to match?

I see one **potential** gotcha in your code.

If the right edge of a row is a mine, it will `print('*')` rather than `println('*')`. To solve this, do println() irregardless of what was in the cell if it's on the right of a row - don't have logic to print OR println content, just println() with no arguments on its own.

EDIT: And as Charlie mentions in the comments to the original question, you have to code your program to handle more than one field and to print Field #num: before each field.

Meaning instead of putting all your code in main, you should put the code that creates and solves one field into its own method and call that from main while there is still input to read.

Comment: Thank you very much about those advice. Most of people here disrespect the beginner problems and this is so disappointing. thank you